# Find and remove multiple audio tracks in video using ffmpeg

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I have 1 video which has multiple audios in it. There are some dialogues and few different soundtracks. But, when i use `ffmpeg -i 1.mp4` it shows only 2 streams.

Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 2964 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 90k tbn, 48 tbc (default)

Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 125 kb/s (default)

Its showing only 1 audio stream, If i remove that stream whole video will be mute. But, i only want to remove particular soundtrack from video, and its not showing separate audio stream for different soundtracks and dialogue used in video.

Comment: Looks like the audio track is a mixdown. Can't do this with ffmpeg - at least not well.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this with single audio stream.
You could filter out some frequencies with other filters but this is far from perfect solution.